# exact utc time and localtime converted to utc time are different python

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I tried printing the exact UTC time  and then tried printing the UTC time by first getting local time and then converting it into UTC time but they had 11 mins difference

Why does this happen and how do I fix this so that I get the correct UTC time that is one printed when I directly get UTC time

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo
import tzlocal
import pytz

local_time =datetime.now()
tz = tzlocal.get_localzone()
print(tz)

utc_time = local_time.replace(tzinfo=tz).astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_time)
correct_utc =datetime.utcnow()
print(correct_utc)
```

output

```
Asia/Colombo
2021-07-18 01:54:31.442555+00:00
2021-07-18 01:43:31.619536
```

I have to make to make a program that takes datetime strings and then convert them into datetime objects and then converts them to utc so using astimezone will be pointless as the program will be running in cloud so it doesnt know the timezone it has to convert from

Comment: `utc_time = local_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)` gives the correct values so that would make me think that it has to do with replace.

Comment: @henry-ecker that is not what i want because in my purpose i will give program some strings and it will convert it to datetime objects and then convert them into utc time

Comment: If your server and client are in different time zones you'll have no choice but to send the zone from the client to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue could be in the `replace` function argument `tzinfo=tz`. `tzinfo` is expecting a `dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile` object and the `tz` you're passing in is a `pytz.tzfile.Asia/Colombo` object from the `pytz` library. You can workaround the issue by instead of using `tzinfo=tz`, you can convert `tz` to string type using `str(tz)` function and then use the function `dateutil.tz.gettz` to get the timezone's `dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile` object (`tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz(str(tz))`)

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo
import tzlocal
import pytz
import dateutil.tz

local_time =datetime.now()
tz = tzlocal.get_localzone()
print(tz)

utc_time = local_time.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz(str(tz))).astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_time)
correct_utc =datetime.utcnow()
print(correct_utc)
```

Comment: with Python 3.9, you neither require pytz nor dateutil (third party libraries) - you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard library.